# How can I solve cannot import name 'fetch_openml' from 'sklearn.datasets'

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm learning sklearn, but I can't use `fetch_openml()`. It says,

> ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch_openml' from 'sklearn.datasets'

Comment: `fetch_openml()` has been deprecated. What is your scikit-learn version?

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of sklearn, it's even easier to fetch open ML Datasets. For example, you can add import and fetch mnist dataset as:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
X, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True, as_frame=False)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
```

For more details check [official example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sparse_logistic_regression_mnist.html?highlight=mnist).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `fetch_mldata` has been deprecated in the newer `sklearn`. Use [`load_digits`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-lle-digits-py) to achieve loading the MNIST data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem in jupyter  follow these steps:

1. Download file mnist-original from " [https://osf.io/jda6s/"](https://osf.io/jda6s/%22)
2. after download file copy it into C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\scikit_learn_data\mldata
3. in notebook jupyter do:

   ```
   from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
   mnist = fetch_mldata('mnist-original')
   ```